# ORA-01858 error by using DatePicker in Classic Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

in APEX (v22) I have a Classic Report (using the template 'cards'), which have the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') AS CARD_TITLE,
COUNT(EMP_NUMBER) AS CARD_TEXT
FROM mytable
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yy-mm-dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P02_FROM, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE(:P02_TO, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') DESC
```

Let me explain a little bit before I come to the problem:

- :P02_FROM and :P02_TO are the DatePicker, which have the Format Mask 'YYYY-MM-DD'; also there is a dynamic action for each one, which submit the page;
- SUBMIT_DATE is also in the table mytable with the type DATE
- the WHERE-Clause have also more entries, because there is a search filter in this page. Because of the ORA error this is not so important in this context and I don't write this here.

And now I have the following **phenomen or problem**:
When I press to 'Save and Run' in APEX, I see all the cards. When I switch to another page in this application and switch back to this page, I get the ORA-01858 error. ***AND***: when I refresh the settings of the search filter on this page for example, the cards come back and this ORA error disappear. Why?

On the one side I tried it with TO_DATE or TO_CHAR or with TRUNC for this ORA error but it doesn't appear and comes in the same way as described above. On the other side I don't know why this ORA error comes and go by refreshing the page.

And there is one additional info for this SUBMIT_DATE: In the WHERE-Clause it must be in the format 'dd-mm-yy'; if not, I get the ORA error at the beginning of the page-refresh and this time it doesn't appear. But on the other side, I need it in the format 'yyyy-mm'.

So, can anyone help me to fix this phenomen/problem? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If `SUBMIT_DATE` is a date then you should not pass it to `to_date()`. That will do implicit conversion to a string, using your current NLS settings, and then convert back to a date - which could work, sometimes, but it more likely to error (as you're seeing) or get unexpected results. It's also not a good idea to use 2-digit years.

So you can do:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') AS CARD_TITLE,
COUNT(EMP_NUMBER) AS CARD_TEXT
FROM mytable
WHERE SUBMIT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P02_FROM, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE(:P02_TO, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') DESC
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNCS(SUBMIT_DATE, 'MM'), 'yyyy-mm') AS CARD_TITLE,
  COUNT(EMP_NUMBER) AS CARD_TEXT
FROM mytable
WHERE SUBMIT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P02_FROM, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE(:P02_TO, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY TRUNC(SUBMIT_DATE, 'MM')
ORDER BY TRUNC(SUBMIT_DATE, 'MM') DESC
```

But either way, `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so that will match rows where `SUBMIT_DATE` is on or after midnight on the FROM date, and up to exactly midnight on the TO date.

You might actually want:

```
WHERE SUBMIT_DATE >= TO_DATE(:P02_FROM, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND SUBMIT_DATE < TO_DATE(:P02_TO, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + 1
```

which would include all data on the TO date, at any time of day. (Or remove the +1 if you don't want to include data from that TO date at all.)

---

You might be tempted to do:

```
WHERE TRUNC(SUBMIT_DATE, 'DD') BETWEEN ...
```

and that might be what you were trying to do with `to_date()` - i.e. making the time portion midnight - which wouldn't error if you explicitly converted to a string:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN ...
```

... though `trunc()` is shorter and cleaner.

While that approach would work, and include all data from the TO date, applying a function to the column would prevent a normal index on that column being used. It's usually better to use the `>=` and `<` filters instead of `between` so you don't have to modify the column value for the comparison.

Comment: First of all: thank you for your answer; I tried your solutions but I get the same ORA error in the same way described above; I modify the where-clause (with your help) and now I use >= and < instead of between.

Comment: Are the FROM and TO bind arguments actually passed as strings, or as dates? I wold think Apex would supply dates, but I don't use it, so not sure - and your description implies they are passed as strings. But it if does pass as dates then you don't need the `to_date()` calls around those either.

Comment: I have tried it without the 'to_date' and I get the ORA-001861 error. So the FROM and TO are strings.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of possiblities I solved it and I have realized that I didn't write one additional point: Both of the DatePicker had a deprecated version and different settings, which are not consistent working with the other attributes. So I change it to newest HTML version and set everything to its default setting. After this change it works, also using the tip of Alex Poole. Thank you for the help.